# How do I leave space after end of struct to allow for future ABI changes?

Tags: rust

I want to call [`WSALookupServiceNext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms741641(v=vs.85).aspx), which is an `extern C` function with a simplified interface like:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo {
    version: u32,
    a: u32,
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn get_foo(p: *mut Foo, nbytes: *mut u32) -> i32;
}
```

You give it pointer to a `Foo` struct and `nbytes = ::std::mem::size_of::<Foo>()`, and it fills the struct if everything is OK.

If the ABI changes after the program is compiled, like this:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo {
    version: u32,
    a: u32,
    b: f64,
}
```

Then the function indicates a failure and `nbytes` will contain the correct size of `Foo`. How should I handle such situation?

In C or C++, I would simplify my life and do:

```
union {
  struct Foo foo;
  char buf[4000];//should be enough for 10 years
} a;
uint32_t nbytes = sizeof(a);
if (get_foo(&a.foo, &nbytes) != 0) {
  return -1;
}
```

Is this possible in Rust? If not, how I should alloc space with size > `size_of::<Foo>()` but with a pointer to `Foo`? `Foo` is generated by [bindgen](https://github.com/servo/rust-bindgen) so I can not change its declaration and add bytes to the end of it.

I'm using Rust 1.15.1.

Comment: "*The problem if ABI changed*" ... did you mean to say "API"? Do I understand you correctly in that you want to make your Rust code work with  different versions of a type within a C library? I don't think you should do that. Your Rust code should target an exact version of the struct instead of using hacks like this to make it "kind of work". If you want your Rust code to work with different versions of a C library, use cargo features and conditional compilation.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt It is hard to decide API or ABI, but because of after C binary update, you can rebuild Rust program without any source modification and it continues to work, I call it ABI. I can not target exact version, I want my code to work with as many versions of Windows as I can. So after I write code to work with windows 10 SDK, I want my code to work with windows 11 SDK and so on without modifications and rebuild. It is possible on `C`, why not on `Rust`?

Comment: You can add a dummy array of bytes in Rust, too: `_filler_dummy: [u8; 4000],`. I am just saying that I don't think it's a good solution to this problem. But then again, I don't know too much about FFI guidelines, so maybe someone else can clarify.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt But where should I add `_filler_dummy`? Note that I can NOT modify `Foo` declaration. That's why in `C` variant I use `union`.

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense allocating (e.g. using malloc) a buffer and transmuting the pointer to `*mut Foo` in this case?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson What about align requirements for `*mut Foo` if I just allocate memory?

Comment: `malloc` is defined to return memory suitable for any C object's alignment (which should be fine for something you're using with C).  Otherwise I guess [mem::align_of<T>()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.align_of.html) can be used.

Comment: This [thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5weidf/no_stable_mallocfree_in_rust_stdlib/) covers allocating raw memory in Rust itself.

Comment: Your use case is not what I'd call typical C code. While it's true that some Win32 API functions do support evolving the structure, those functions typically include the size of the structure as part of the structure itself, which allows Windows itself to maintain ABI compatibility. That setup doesn't require the kind of union that you are describing. Can you give more details regarding your attempts to `WSALookupServiceNext `? Which structure would correspond to `Foo`?

Comment: @user4815162342 `WSALookupServiceNext` take exactly one struct, this struct `Foo` is represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nightly builds of Rust have [untagged unions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32836), so you could the same workaround you would use in C/C++.

```
#![feature(untagged_unions)]

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo {
    version: u32,
    a: u32,
    b: f64,
}

#[repr(C)]
union PaddedFoo {
    foo: Foo,
    _padding: [u8; 4000],
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Foo>());
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<PaddedFoo>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum (also called tagged union), it already includes some space for the type tag and accessing the inner value is less convenient. [Nightly builds of Rust have untagged unions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1444-union.md), but that is not stable yet and reading or borrowing a field of it requires unsafe code. As the comments indicate you could manually allocate. The straight forward way is using a struct that includes the struct, allocating the outer:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo {
    version: u32,
    a: u32,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct FooPadded {
    foo: Foo,
    _reserved: [u8; 4000],
}
```